# Angular: How to make a button appears once you focus an input (search box)?

Tags: angularjs

I am working in a mobile application where I have a search box and at the right side there is a clear button, obviously to clean the search box when you decide.

I have a directive that I do not know why is not working:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('FocusOnVisibility', function($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
              console.log(scope.showInput)
        //Watch the showInput model
        scope.$watch('showInput', function () {
            //If the model changes to true, focus on the element
            if (scope.showInput === undefined) {
                //Assumes that the element has the focus method
                //If not, then you can have your own logic to focus here
                element.focus();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

and this is the search box with the button I want to become displayed once focus that input

```
    <label>
       <!--once focus this input, the button below must be shown-->
      <input type="search"
             ng-click="showInput=true
             ng-model="query">
    </label>

    <button class="button-clear" FocusOnVisibility
            ng-show="showInput"
            ng-click="query = null">
      CANCEL
    </button>
```

**UPDATE**

I fix it already by adding `ng-click="showInput=true"` to the input field, but now the issue I have is that the button does not disappears once you leave the input.

Comment: a better description of what is happening when the directive fires (console logs, perhaps) would help here, but I can only assume that `element` isn't defined or in scope inside the `$watch` function.

Comment: I fix it already but now the button does not disappears once you leave, I just add: ```ng-click="showInput=true"``` to the input field.

Comment: look at my update and let me explain: what I want to is a search very similar to the facebook mobile app.

Comment: ok looking again, yes setting `showInput=true` would work to trigger your function, but where are you setting `showInput` to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has this capability out of the box:

```
<input ng-focus="showButton = true" ng-blur="showButton = false">
<button ng-show="showButton">wat</button>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OdioVG0928ku3plsCJ3f)